# Check Android SDK Version with Kotlin using when

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk

I want to check the *Android* SDK version at runtime. I tried it like so:

```
fun Context.getDrawableById(resId : Int) : Drawable {

    when (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {

        in Int.MIN_VALUE..20 -> return resources.getDrawable(resId)
        else -> return getDrawable(resId)
    }
}
```

I got a compiler warning *"Call requires API Level 21 (current min is 19)"*. So I changed my code:

```
fun Context.getDrawableById(resId : Int) : Drawable {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21)
        return resources.getDrawable(resId)
    else
        return getDrawable(resId)
}
```

No compiler warning.

My question is: is it possible to use `when` in this case without compiler warning? How?

Comment: Android APIs start from 1, why use range from -2147483648 :) ? Looks like compiler doesn't validate the ranges properly, but in most cases You only need to check for one one explicit API Level where your required method was added, so chance for this to be "fixed" are pretty small.

Comment: @Pawel i know that API starts from 1, but it did not solve it. Of course, my first try was: "in 1..20" and "else". I thought the combination out of "Int.MIN_VALUE..20" and "else" covers all possibilites.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is it possible to use "when" in this case without compiler warning?

Yes, by using `ContextCompat.getDrawable()` instead of `context.getDrawable()`:

```
fun View.getDrawable(resId : Int): Drawable? =
        when (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
            in 1..20 -> resources.getDrawable(resId)
            else -> ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resId)
        }
```

Note that `ContextCompat.getDrawable()` returns the optional type `Drawable?`.